# Splitting a number in half but fixing when second half starts with 0

Tags: php, regex

I have a large number that I want to split in half. For this example, let's use: `5639445604728832`

When it is split in half it comes out like this:

```
56394456
04728832
```

Obviously, the second number isn't a number anymore.

I have the following code, but I am trying to make it so it will add the `0`'s to the end of the first number until the second number is officially a real number. Could anyone help me solve this?

```
function my_number_split($number)
{
    $half = (int) ( (strlen($number) / 2) ); // cast to int incase str length is odd
    $left = substr($number, 0, $half);
    $right = substr($number, $half);

    echo $left."<br />".$right;
}
```

Comment: `$half = (int) ( (strlen($number) / 2) );` --> Don't do this! Please! This is a bad idea and it's hard to understand what you want. Try `$half = strlen($number) >> 1;` (same as removing 1 bit, which is the same as dividing by 2 and rounding) or `$half = ceil( (strlen($number) / 2) );` (`ceil()` round up, use `floor()` to round down). Both methods are better and easier to read.

Comment: Will do @IsmaelMiguel, thanks for mentioning this to cpilko as well

Comment: You're welcome. This is a very commun mistake and I did it a few times. I find it easier to use the bitshifting way. And faster. But go for readability. The bit-shifting is a micro-optimization. And those may be evil is badly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your function like this would do the trick.

```
function my_number_split($number)
{
    $half = ceil( (strlen($number) / 2) ); 
    while (0 == substr($number, $half, 1) && $half <= strlen($number) ) $half++;
    $left = substr($number, 0, $half);
    $right = substr($number, $half);

    echo $left."<br />".$right;
}
```

Comment: `(int) ( (strlen($number) / 2) );` You meant `strlen($number) >> 1;`?

Comment: I know, but that is bad idea. If you don't like bit shifting, use `floor( strlen($number) / 2 )` (or `ceil()`) which is better that what you have currently..

Comment: True that. Why not comment on the OP's post?

Comment: Because you made the same mistake as he did. But I will comment.

Comment: Thank you for fixing it up a bit and for everyones comments.

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop should do it.
Something like this -

```
function my_number_split($number)
{
    /* Logic to traverse ahead till a 0 is not found. */
    $str_len = strlen($number);
    $half_index = $str_len/2;
    while($half_index < $str_len){
        if($number[$half_index] != "0"){
            break;
        }
        $half_index++;
    }
    //Slicing string.
    $left = substr($number, 0, $half_index);
    $right = substr($number, $half_index);
    echo $left."<br />".$right;
}
my_number_split("5639445604728832");

/*
OUTPUT -
563944560
4728832
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an inefficient way, but for the challenge:

```
if (preg_match('~\A(?<n1>.?(?:.(?=.*(.(?(2)\2)\z)))+0*)(?<n2>.+)~', $number, $m))
    echo $m['n1'] . "\n" . $m['n2'];
```

Comment: haha I like your reasoning. I unfortunately am not at this level of understanding regex soooo i'm gonna have to pass on this one. Very very cool though.